# what is the Interpolation of Hermitian Toeplitz which owns a low-rank property?

Tags: convex-optimization, interpolation, nuclear-norm

I was studying Direction of Arrival (DOA) and I ran into an article that indicated that the
"desired covariance matrix is Hermitian Toeplitz and owns the low-rank property, the covariance matrix of the interpolated ULA can be recovered by solving the minimization problem"

- Note that R is the covariance matrix of received samples.

$$
             min_{\bar{R_v} \in C^{\|V^+\|\times \|{V^+}\|} } rank(\bar{R_v})  
                                                          $$
subject to:

$$ \bar{R_v} = \bar{R^H_v}
;<\bar{R_v}>_{n1,n2} = <{R_v}>_{n1,n2} ; n1,n2 \in V^+ , n1-n2 \in D   $$

where *H* denotes the Hermitian notation and D, is a different set (the smaller set) and V is the virtual set of ULA (the more extensive set to be interpolated).

The constraints above can ensure that $$\bar{R_v}$$ is a Hermitian Toeplitz matrix, and
the known correlation information on D is entirely contained in $$R_V$$.

Clearly, the minimization problem above is a nonconvex NP-hard problem. By using the nuclear norm minimization, can be reformulated as:

$$
             min_{\bar{R_v} \in C^{\|V^+\|\times \|{V^+}\|} } \|(\bar{R_v}) \|_{*} 
                                                          $$
subject to:

$$ \bar{R_v} = \bar{R^H_v}
;<\bar{R_v}>_{n1,n2} = <{R_v}>_{n1,n2} ; n1,n2 \in V^+ , n1-n2 \in D   $$

I'm seeking the reason why I can interpolate the Covariance matrix using that minimization problem!? Is there any reference on this matter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm seeking the reason why I can interpolate the Covariance matrix using that minimization problem!?

Comment: What are the meanings of $\|V^+\|,\|V^-\|,\bar{R}_v$, and "ULA", please ?

Comment: Uniform Linear Array (ULA) is a form of structured array in antenna arrays. it is not the main concern here, the main concern is with the math point of view where you can get an interpolation of a Hermitian Toeplitz by solving such a minimization problem!

Comment: You have answered about ULA, but not about notations... I must not be the single one not able to understand them... when I see that nobody answers you...

Comment: $$\bar{R_{v}}$$ is the target covariance matrix to be interpolated from $$R_{v}$$ covariance matrix which is a Toeplitz matrix as mentioned above!

Comment: V+ and V- are the sets that represent the array space on a single line (image x-axis) and include -M to M with stepsize equal to 1. also D is the difference set of 2 different ULAs. if it help imagine V is the sum of those 2 ULAs and D is the difference. also V+ means 0:M instead of -M:1:M.